# Activerecord transaction concurrency race condition issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, transactions

I'm currently doing live testing of a game I'm making for Android. The services are written in rails 3.1 and I'm using Postgresql. Some of my more technically savvy testers have been able to manipulate the game by recording their requests to the server and replaying them with high concurrency. I'll try to briefly describe the scenario below without getting caught up in the code.

- A user can purchase multiple items, each item has its own record in the database.
- The request goes to a controller action, which creates a purchase model to record information about the transaction.
- The trade model has a method that sets up the purchase of the items. It essentially does a few logical steps to see if they can purchase the item. The most important is that they have a limit of 100 items per user at any given time. If all the conditions pass, a simple loop is used to create the number of items they requested.

So, what they are doing is, recording 1 valid request purchase via a proxy. Then replaying it with high concurrency, which essentially is allowing a few extra to slip through each time. So if they set it to purchase 100 quantity, they can get it up to 300-400 or if they do 15 quantity, they can get it up to like 120.

The above purchase method is wrapped in a transaction. However, even though its wrapped it won't stop it in certain circumstances where the requests are executing nearly at the same time. I'm guessing this may require some DB locking. Another twist in this that needs to be known is that at any given time rake task are being ran in cron jobs against the user table to update the players health and energy attributes. So, that cannot be blocked either.

Any assistance would be really awesome. This is my little hobby side project and I want to make sure the game is fair and fun for everyone.

Thanks so much!

Controller action:

```
  def hire
    worker_asset_type_id = (params[:worker_asset_type_id])
    quantity = (params[:quantity])

    trade = Trade.new()

    trade_response = trade.buy_worker_asset(current_user, worker_asset_type_id, quantity)

    user = User.find(current_user.id, select: 'money')

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {
        render json: {
            trade: trade,
            user: user,
            messages: {
                messages: [trade_response.to_s]
            }
        }
      }
    end
  end
```

Trade Model Method:

```
def buy_worker_asset(user, worker_asset_type_id, quantity)
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do

      if worker_asset_type_id.nil?
        raise ArgumentError.new("You did not specify the type of worker asset.")
      end

      if quantity.nil?
        raise ArgumentError.new("You did not specify the amount of worker assets you want to buy.")
      end

      if quantity <= 0
        raise ArgumentError.new("Please enter a quantity above 0.")
      end

      quantity = quantity.to_i
      worker_asset_type = WorkerAssetType.where(id: worker_asset_type_id).first

      if worker_asset_type.nil?
        raise ArgumentError.new("There is no worker asset of that type.")
      end

      trade_cost = worker_asset_type.min_cost * quantity

      if (user.money < trade_cost)
        raise ArgumentError.new("You don't have enough money to make that purchase.")
      end

      # Get the users first geo asset, this will eventually have to be dynamic
      potential_total = WorkerAsset.where(user_id: user.id).length + quantity

      # Catch all for most people
      if potential_total > 100
        raise ArgumentError.new("You cannot have more than 100 dealers at the current time.")
      end

      quantity.times do
        new_worker_asset = WorkerAsset.new()
        new_worker_asset.worker_asset_type_id = worker_asset_type_id
        new_worker_asset.geo_asset_id = user.geo_assets.first.id
        new_worker_asset.user_id = user.id
        new_worker_asset.clocked_in = DateTime.now

        new_worker_asset.save!
      end

      self.buyer_id = user.id
      self.money = trade_cost
      self.worker_asset_type_id = worker_asset_type_id
      self.trade_type_id = TradeType.where(name: "market").first.id
      self.quantity = quantity

      # save trade
      self.save!

      # is this safe?
      user.money = user.money - trade_cost

      user.save!
    end
  end
```

Comment: How about pushing the data integrity logic into the database as a set of CHECK constraints and triggers? Yes, you're never ever supposed to put logic in the database 'cuz this is Rails but that's an absurd and ignorant attitude.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for the suggestion, I'm willing to do something like this as a last resort. I wanna try doing it the Rails way first, if there is a good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need idempotent requests so that request replay is ineffective. Where possible implement operations so that repeating them has no effect. Where not possible, give each request a unique request identifier and record whether requests have been satisfied or not. You can keep the request ID information in an `UNLOGGED` table in PostgreSQL or in redis/memcached since you don't need it to be persistent. This will prevent a whole class of exploits.

To deal with just this one problem create an `AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ... FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE` trigger on the user items table. Have this trigger:

```
BEGIN
    -- Lock the user so only one tx can be inserting/deleting items for this user
    -- at the same time
    SELECT 1 FROM user WHERE user_id = <the-user-id> FOR UPDATE;

    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        IF (SELECT count(user_item_id) FROM user_item WHERE user_item.user_id = <the-user-id>) > 100 THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Too many items already owned, adding this item would exceed the limit of 100 items';
        END IF;
    ELIF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
       -- No action required, all we needed to do is take the lock
       -- so a concurrent INSERT won't run until this tx finishes
    ELSE 
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unhandled trigger case %',TG_OP;
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
```

Alternately, you can implement the same thing in the Rails application by taking row-level lock on the customer ID before adding or deleting any item ownership records. I prefer to do this sort of thing in triggers where you can't forget to apply it somewhere, but I realise you might prefer to do it at the app level. See [Pessimistic locking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html).

Optimistic locking is not a great fit for this application. You can use it by incrementing the lock counter on the user before adding/removing items, but it'll cause row churn on the users table and is really unnecessary when your transactions will be so short anyway.

Comment: Cool thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. I'm going to try to implement this now and see how it goes. Thanks again!

Comment: Works great. I basically just used the built in Rails pessimistic locking like you suggested. As follows:

User.transaction do
      user = User.find(user_id, lock: true)
end

Thanks again man.

Comment: @Jerry I'd still suggest implementing request idempotency. It'll protect you from a whole class of replay exploits. (I'm actually really frustrated that web frameworks don't offer this as a simple request option);.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll definitely consider implementing request idempotency. As of now the lock is a quick fix which seems to be working really nicely, no one has been able to exploit the game using their previous techniques. However, to really insure the integrity of the game I'm willing to implement whatever it takes to keep the game legit.

Answer (score 0):

We can't help much unless you show us your relevant schema and queries. I suppose that you do something like:

```
$ start transaction;
$ select amount from itemtable where userid=? and itemid=?;
15
$ update itemtable set amount=14 where userid=? and itemid=?;
commit;
```

An you should do something like:

```
$ start transaction;
$ update itemtable set amount=amount-1 returning amount where userid=? and itemid=?;
14
$ commit;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I'm reading your correctly, it is assumed that the item already exists in an item table. What is actually happening is, I'm creating an these assets on the fly when a person purchases them.